# macro prompt not getting refreshed in scheduled report

Tags: cognos

I have a date prompt which is set to default to today's date using a prompt macro. The report is scheduled to run daily using today's date but every day it runs it takes the date on which the report was scheduled. My schedule says to run the report and not just view the report.How do I schedule a report to run using refreshed dates? (cognos 10.1)

Comment: Can you post your macro code, and also explain how you are scheduling it. When  you schedule it you should _not_ enter a date at all, otherwise your macro default will not take effect.

Comment: `#prompt( 'Current Day', 'date','_add_days(current_date, -1)')#` is the code I'm using for the macro prompt. But the date doesn't default to yesterday even though I do _add_days(x,-1). So, I subtract 1 using javascript. I have re-scheduled my reports leaving the date field blank as you said and the report ran for yesterday. I have no idea how the javascript ran. I'm still waiting for tomorrow's schedule to see if it takes today's date. I'll keep you posted.

Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Javascript does not run for scheduled reports because there is no 'browser' for it to run in. If you have been scheduling your reports and providing a value for your date parameter then that explains it - your macro prompt will not use a default if you supply a parameter value. Also on the actual prompt page make sure the prompt is not required.

Comment: Why don't you add a filter to your report with calculation from your macro?

Comment: The date prompt has been applied as a filter for my flash sales report which is always as of yesterday.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I just left the date go blank while scheduling the reports and its working as expected on the second day as well. But I have no idea how that became possible. Either `_add_days(current_date, -1)` executed to take yesterday's date or the javascript ran, which is less likely since there is no open browser for it to execute. But anyways, I'm out of trouble. Thanks guys for the discussion.

Comment: I have added my explanation as an answer so anyone else can take advantage of it - does it make sense to you? If you save a date in a scheduled report, that fixed date is used always. It does not use any javascript etc. to set it while being scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not run for scheduled reports because there is no 'browser' for it to run in. If you have been scheduling your reports and *providing* a value for your date parameter then that explains it - your macro prompt will not use a default, ti is using a fixed parameter value instead.

Also on the actual prompt page make sure the prompt is not required.

Comment: I am convinced that the date gets refreshed everyday when I leave the date field go blank while scheduling but I have no idea how it took yesterday's date. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but the expression `_add_days(current_date, -1)` always returns yesterdays date. The parameter `Current Day` will use this as it's default if nothing is supplied to it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using prompt macro, you will have to include JavaScript to pre-select the dynamic date values within the date prompt.

This article on developerWorks details the necessary steps, prompt macro and Javascript to set dynamic default values for date prompts.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-reporting-scripting_techniques-page634/

Comment: Java script does not execute within scheduled reports. It only executes when there is an actual web browser window for it to execute in.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but a good reference. I had to figure  out that for myself.